# PHP MVC folder structure - Where to place new files

Tags: php

If I am using this php file structure: https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal

1. Can someone tell where I put my stylesheets, would I create a "static" folder at the same level as views? Or instead put that whole structure in a folder called "application" and then put "public" folder outside it?
2. If I have divisions or folders, such as "admin", "blog", "forum", where do I put those PHP files, would again I make a folder called "admin" in the same level as "views", and put my admin page templates in there?

Any input on this would be appreciated.

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For css files you may create a folder named css in your app/public folder. If you have folder like admin forum etc you put them into app/public folder. You may also refer [this page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/project-structure.project.html) to have a better understanding of the MVC structure

Answer (score 1):

1 -> You can create a folder to use it as public folder at the same lavel where you can store your css,js and other files and access them as required.

2 -> You can create classes respectively with required methods in classes folder and create the view files in the view.

You have to be careful about the paths for accessing them.